# "${foo//@(...)/}" works only in command line but not in a script

Tags: bash, shell

I have the below command `"${CHROMEDRIVER//@([\/])/}"` is shell file and on running `bash file.sh`, it doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash

CHROMEDRIVER="75.0.3770.8/"
echo $CHROMEDRIVER
echo "${CHROMEDRIVER//@([\/])/}"
```

[image: Screenshot showing unwanted slashes in output]

But, when I run the same cmd `"${CHROMEDRIVER//@([\/])/}"` in terminal, it works great

[image: Screenshot showing slashes removed on interactive invocation]

Comment: `echo "${CHROMEDRIVER%/}"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command requires `extglob` support to be enabled. Presumably you're turning it on (with `shopt -s extglob`) in your dotfiles, but it's off-by-default in scripts.

See [the bash-hackers' wiki on extended pattern language](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern#extended_pattern_language), describing the specific items that require the `extglob` flag to be enabled; `@(...)` is among them.

Thus, to fix your script without changing the pattern you're replacing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob

CHROMEDRIVER="75.0.3770.8/"
echo "$CHROMEDRIVER"
echo "${CHROMEDRIVER//@([\/])/}"
```

...though insofar as your goal is just to strip a trailing slash, use `"${CHROMEDRIVER%/}"` instead, as described in [the bash-hackers' wiki page on parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).